# Designing a URL Shortening service like TinyURL

Tags: algorithm, hash, system

I'm reading an online document that explains how to design a url shortening service. The website is https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview .

In the section, Encoding actual URL, they said ->
"We can compute a unique hash (e.g., MD5 or SHA256, etc.) of the given URL. The hash can then be encoded for displaying. This encoding could be base36 ([a-z ,0-9]) or base62 ([A-Z, a-z, 0-9]) and if we add ‘+’ and ‘/’ we can use Base64 encoding. A reasonable question would be, what should be the length of the short key? 6, 8, or 10 characters."

"If we use the MD5 algorithm as our hash function, it’ll produce a 128-bit hash value. After base64 encoding, we’ll get a string having more than 21 characters (since each base64 character encodes 6 bits of the hash value).Since we only have space for 8 characters per short key, how will we choose our key then? We can take the first 6 (or 8) letters for the key. This could result in key duplication, to resolve that, we can choose some other characters out of the encoding string or swap some characters."

I used online MD5 hash generator (http://onlinemd5.com/) and Base64 encoder (https://www.base64encode.org/) to verify the above. I used "www.yahoo.com" as the input string for MD5 hash and output is 1B03577ED104F16AADC00A639D33CB44 . Then I Base64 encoded it and got MUIwMzU3N0VEMTA0RjE2QUFEQzAwQTYzOUQzM0NCNDQ= with UTF-8 destination charset and Unix newline seperator.

Can anyone explain if I'm doing it correctly? I see the number of characters are way more than 21.

Comment: Each of the 32 characters in the MD5 hash represents 4 bits. So you need to combine them to create 8-bit values. For example the first byte is hex 1B, which is decimal 27. After you've got an array of 16 bytes, then you can Base64 encode it.

Comment: After reading this tutorial - https://www.lifewire.com/base64-encoding-overview-1166412 and the comment below, I have understood it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the output of MD5 as a string of hexadecimal digits, and then base64 encoding that string.  There's no reason to base64 encode that string - base64 encoding is intended for binary data.  What you probably wanted to do is base64 the actual 128-bit binary value of the MD5 hash.  Here is some Python code that does what I think you are trying to do:

```
import hashlib, base64

text = "www.yahoo.com"
text_utf8 = text.encode('utf8')
md5 = hashlib.md5(text_utf8).digest()
b64 = base64.b64encode(md5)
print(b64)
```

This gets the result `GwNXftEE8WqtwApjnTPLRA` which has the length you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This post has helped me to really understand the algorithm behind [TinyUrl design](https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview)
Here is the sample java program, if anyone is looking for it.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class TinyUrlAlgorithm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] input = "https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview".getBytes("UTF-8");//args[0].getBytes("UTF-16");//"https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-the-system-design-interview".getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] md5hash = messageDigest.digest(input);
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String encodeToString = encoder.encodeToString(md5hash);
        int shortKeyType =  3;//Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String tinyUrlKey = shortKeyType ==1 ? encodeToString.substring(0,6) : shortKeyType == 2 ? encodeToString.substring(0,8) : randomlySelect8Chars(encodeToString);
        System.out.println("ShortKey --> " + tinyUrlKey);

    }

    //Fisher yates algorithm
    private static String randomlySelect8Chars(String encodeToString) {
        Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        char[] encodedChars =  encodeToString.toCharArray();
        assert encodedChars.length == 21;
        for(int i=20; i >=0; i--) {
            int randomIndex =  random.nextInt(i+1);
            swap(encodedChars,randomIndex,i);
        }

        return new String(encodedChars,0,8);
    }

    private static void swap(char[] chars, int i, int j) {
        char temp = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[j];
        chars[j] = temp;
    }
}
```